# How to differentiate between draft versions in ModelEvent?

Tags: craft3

craftcms/cms : 3.6

First create new entry and it store as draft

then i publish this entry

then create a new draft version of this published entry

so how to differentiate this is first draft or second draft in "ModelEvent"?

```
Event::on(Entry::class, Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE, function(ModelEvent $e) { });
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
 Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
        function (ModelEvent $event) {
            if (ElementHelper::isDraft($event->sender)) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    );
```

Also you can configure it here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/events.html

[image]

Or you can try this:

```
use craft\events\ModelEvent;
use craft\models\EntryDraft;
use yii\base\Event;

...
Event::on(
    EntryDraft::class,
    EntryDraft::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function (ModelEvent $event) {
        if ($event->sender->firstSave) {
            // ...
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It's work for craft4, but my craft version is craftcms/cms : 3.6. So, please guide for craft3, Thank you.

Comment: @arshitkalkani What part of the code is exactly not working?
Also, you can try `->isNew` instead of `->firstSave` instead?